# Быстрая загрузка статического контента на сайт

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, изображения, сервисы, облачное-хранилище

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите пожалуйста, стоит ли использовать облачные сервисы для хранения и получения картинок для сайта. 
Есть ли преимущества использовать облачные сервисы вместо своего сервера???
Если есть преимущества, то подскажите какие хорошие сервисы существуют.

Какие есть варианты чтобы оптимизировать загрузку изображений

Comment: Хорошие и бесплатные, да? )

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 2):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, стоит ли использовать облачные сервисы для
>   хранения и получения картинок для сайта

1. Если вы хотите, чтобы у пользователей была нормальная скорость загрузки, то да.
2. Если вы хотите чтоб в случае проблем с вашим сервером картинок люди всё равно смогли их получать, то да.

> Есть ли преимущества использовать облачные сервисы вместо своего
>   сервера???

Можно настроить CDN (content delivery network), который будет забирать контент с вашего сервера и кешировать у себя. Пользователь уже будет получать картинки с этого CDN, что намного быстрее. То есть, при первом запросе на конкретную картинку CDN качает её с вашего сервера, кеширует у себя на время, которое вы в настройках укажите. Больше он в течении этого времени не будет обращаться к вашему серваку.

Шанс, что сломается CDN куда меньше, чем вашего сервера. К тому же, ваш сервер находится в конкретной зоне, следовательно загрузка контента из каких-то частей света будет медленной. CDN имеют распределённую структуру, они реплицируют ваши данные по разным датацентрам, чтоб максимизировать скорость из всех регионов.

В случае с Amazon, можно CDN настроить так, чтоб он картинки брал из вашего Amazon S3 хранилища. Тогда вам вообще не нужен сервер собственный с картинками.

> Если есть преимущества, то подскажите какие хорошие сервисы
>   существуют.

Если мы говорим о CDN, то лично мы используем [cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) и [Azure CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cdn/). Могу их посоветовать. Но это, естественно, платные сервисы. Ещё хорош [fastly](https://www.fastly.com/) (он, вероятно, дешевле будет).

Comment: Привет, я создал s3 и скорость загрузки картинок такая же как и с моего сервера. Я думал что с s3 сервиса будет быстрей, но нет...

Comment: Если оно в том же регионе, что и ваш сервер, то возможно. Плюс, скорость - это лишь один из плюсов.